# Can we call doPost method of servlet from img tag src?

Tags: java, html, servlets

i know it does not make any sense calling doPost method of servlet from img tag src:

```
  <img src='/ServletName' alt=''/>// i know it will call doGet or service method but i can't use these.
```

So is there any way calling doPost method from img tag of html and show image in img tag?

Actually my doPost method response type is :

```
  response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
```

also i cannot store image on disk of server.

Comment: It is called if you submit the form with HTTP POST method.

Comment: Post is to send data to the server. The strange thing you're trying to do is definitely a `get`. The image has to be stored persistently somewhere? Unless you're dynamically generating it...

Comment: thanks for your comment, so i guess answer is no to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *So is there any way calling doPost method from img tag of html and show image in img tag?*

No. That's just the contract of HTML `<img>` element. The webbrowser must download the image by a GET request on the URL as specified in `src` attribute.

Just do the image serving job in `doGet()` method instead. Even more, you can just rename `doPost` to `doGet`. The logic doesn't need to be changed at all.